# BIGCOMMERCE - Add required field based on quantity

Tags: wordpress, bigcommerce

I am designing a T-shirt store for a client and need to be able to add custom fields to a BigCommerce product based on the user requesting more than one product (tshirt)

So - if the user has 2 products - they would be asked to complete  fields for reverse name and size.  Is this possible?

Comment: yes, you have to use a product option field, type text

Comment: Are you talking about on Checkout or on the Specific Product Page?

Do you have a screen shot or some type of example I can look at to get a better idea of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi, it would be on a screen product page - I will post a link when in the office.

Comment: http://www.302618-51.temp-dns.com/st/index.php/product/mens-tee/

Answer (score 1):

There aren't conditional options out of the box in Bigcommerce. You'd have to have unrequired fields that were hidden unless multiple quantities were selected (using javascript to accomplish the hide/show).

Alternatively, you can limit the item so only one can be added to the cart at a time. This could be a negative customer experience though.